# Pre load the site

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new in web development., i have currently worked on a website that has many product images therefore whole page of web site don't load at once, that leaves bad impression,Kindly guide me how to pre load all images of website. Whatever the method is using jquery or any plugin. Please help me!

Comment: The simpliest way would be to hide your content element with css (and possibly show a loading message/bar/image), then on window load, show it.

Comment: Is there any J-query plugin that show progress bar at start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use .load() event in jQuery

```
var imagecount = 10;

$('img').load(function() {
   // Image load complete
   if(imagecount == 0)
      // Loading of all images are over
      LoadingComplete();
   else {
      imagecount--;
      // Here you can update the progress bar.
   }
});
```

For showing progress bar you can use [jQuery progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#animated) plugin

```
 $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
    value: 1
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

`http://www.krio.me/scripttest/imgLoader/`

I have used the plugin provided at the above website.
The reasons it is special because:

1) Images get displayed only when they are completely downloaded

2) Even at downloading speed as low as 30kbps, it preloads the images quickly

3) You do not have to do much, its main purpose is to assist web developers and designers in improving their user interfaces.

Comment: You can also try this: http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS